# Typescript check if a value is string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a component:

```js
export type IDAta = string | number | null;

interface IDAta {
  data?: string | number | null;
  verify: boolean;
}

const App: React.FC<IDAta> = ({
  data = '',
  verify = true,
}) => {

  if ((data || data === 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        {verify && isText(data) ? (
          <Child text={data} />
        ) : (
          data
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

};

export default App;
```

isText and Child component expect the parameters only to be string, but doing this `verify && isText(data)` then i get error in typescript like `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.` . This could be solved as follow:

```js
{
  verify && typeof data === 'string' && isText(data) ? ( 
  <Child text = {data as string}/>
  ) : (
    data
  )
}
```

I am not sure if this solution is ok, because `typeof data === 'string'` double the logic from `isText` function which looks like this:

```js
const isText = (data: string) => {
  return typeof data === 'string';
};
```

Question: What will be the best solution to solve the issue described above?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A [type guard/predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function isText(data: unknown): data is string {
  return typeof data === 'string';
};
```

Comment: it helps, but i try to avoid `any`, is there a solution without using `any`? I want to specify that `data` could be only a string like `data:string`.In your example i specify that returned value could be a value from ANY

Comment: You can use `unknown` instead. Honestly I don't see anything bad in using `any` in this particular case

Comment: @captain-yossarian, in the case above we don't specify that data could be only string, we said that returned value could be anything. In this way i think i loose the strict checking types.

Comment: Return valud of `isText` is a bollean type while argument of function could be anuthing

Comment: @captain-yossarian, `data is string` doesn't mean that returned value is a string?

Comment: No, `data is string` means that it is a special syntax of a typeguard. `isText` returns boolean and helps TS to narrow the type. It is  a confirmation that if `isText` returns `true` - `data is string`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236559/discussion-between-asking-and-captain-yossarian).

Comment: Please read the linked TS handbook article.